# Tkinter GUI canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, coordinates

I am working on a Lego Mindstorms project where we create a GUI that can be used to control the robot. The thing I need to do is to create something that shows the robots position after every move. I am using a canvas where I draw a rectangle and then a dot that shows the current position of the robot. I have a whole bunch of code but I am just showing you a small piece of it relevant to my problem.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

def __init__(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.button = Button(frame, text="Move", command=lambda: do_move())
    self.button.pack(side=TOP)

    self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=300, height=450)
    self.canvas.place(x=250, y=550)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 450, fill="white")
    self.canvas.create_oval(150, 300, 160, 310, fill="blue", tags="Position")

    x, y = self.canvas.coords("Position")
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)

    x2 = self.canvas.canvasx(self.x)
    y2 = self.canvas.canvasy(self.y)
    x2 = int(x2)
    y2 = int(y2)

    def move_forward():
        self.canvas.move(Position, x2, y2)

    def move_backwards():
        self.canvas.move(Position, , )

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)

    root.title("Mindstorms GUI")
    root.geometry("800x1200")

    root.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

For the move function that I have a button for, I choose a value and that value will move the robot forward/backward. When the robot has moved, I want to also move my blue circle on my canvas. X and Y are the coordinates for the circles current position, and the rest about X2 and Y2 are taken from another site. I am not really sure why you have to write x=int(x) and I dont really understand the parts for X2 and Y2. Any explanations and suggestions about how I can write the rest of my code?

The first new function that I define at the end will be used with my move button so that I have two commands for the button. When I click the button, the Position-circle will also be moved to the new coordinates. I will also need to write somewhere that a specific value of the unit I use for my move function equals for example a move of 5 coordinates in my canvas. Any tips on how to do that?

I hope you understand the task and my formulations. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues with your sample code, hopefully this minimal example will help you get on track:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.move_button = Button(self, text="Move", command=self.do_move)
        self.move_button.pack()

        self.random_button = Button(
            self, text="Random!",
            command=self.random_move)
        self.random_button.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=300, height=450)
        self.canvas.config(
            highlightbackground="grey",
            borderwidth=2,
            relief="flat")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_oval(
            150, 300, 160, 310, fill="blue", tag="Oval")

        self.pack()

    def do_move(self):
        self.canvas.move("Oval", 10, 10)

    def random_move(self):
        x = random.randint(1, 290)
        y = random.randint(1, 440)
        self.canvas.coords("Oval", x, y, x+10, y+10)

root = Tk()
root.title("Mindstorms GUI")
root.geometry("400x600")

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Notice that the Canvas `move` method takes an offset. Alternatively, you could use the `coords` method with coordinates as arguments if you know the new location of the oval, however note that the coordinates should be a list of coordinate pairs. I've added a random button to show how to use coords.

Sounds like a cool project, have fun!